# Diffuse bake alpha

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency, uv-image-editor

It's simpe. I have a plane. On that plane is a texture of a leaf with alpha transparency. Works when I render/switch to rendered preview. Now I want to bake that image of a leaf to another plane, so I have 512x512 texture (instead of some random resolution)

[image]

Above is the node set up for the transparent leaf

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And the material for the "low poly" plane that I need the image baked to, is just an image texture with an empty image connected to diffuse connected to surface output. When I bake it, the places that are transparent in the first material, just become black instead.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhmh1l6ikcuiyim/Dandelions.rar?dl=0
Here is the file in case anyone wants to see it-it's ment for UE4 btw. The top layers are the "low poly", more to the right, the lower the texture resolution is, and below them, there are the coresponding "high poly models"

Joke question-How tall are dandelions usually? 15-25cm?

Comment: Also, if you just my file, you need to move the low poly planes on teh last 2 morels a bit, the normals are the wrong way

Comment: now it's even worse, I get completley nothing when i bake it

Comment: In cycle i don't know why you have to create an image texture slot in the node editor of your material and link it to your image. Also try a tranparent shader instead of translucent to bake alpha

Comment: Oh, yea, I just noticed I was using translucent instead of transparent. but still. what is suppose to be alpha is just black. I managed to filter it out in gimp tho.

Answer (score 1):

a color inverter helps when i get that black in my transparent images. maybe give it a shot

Comment: Please elaborate (preferably with screenshots) where the invert node goes. And if you know it, a short explanation of WHY it works is also good.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found solution, or rather  Zacharias Reinhardt from yt.
Simple way to render instead of baking foliage bilboards. No black alpha outline will be seen.
https://youtu.be/BtUS8QTsVZA

Other method would be to model HP plant without alpha for baking bilboards. You can add it for other LODs.

Comment: Answers that rely only on a link are discouraged and likely to be removed in review.  Please elaborate.